# access individual field values from an object element in a list

Tags: apex, map, list

What I am trying to do is to update a child object field (downloads__c) in each of the child records in the child object (Data__c) record collection,
with the value of a field (downloads__c) from its parent object (Parent__c). The parent object also has the field count__c.

Once all the records are updated in the child collection, do a dml insert after the loop. Can't seem to get this to work. Hope I have explained correctly.

```
jsonBody = '[{"count__c":"45","downloads__c":"30"},{"count__c":"40","downloads__c":"20"}]'; // child records to be updated

// Querry parent 
List<Parent__c> parentList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Parent__c 
                WHERE count__c IN :countList]; // countList will have unique values of count__c from the child json records

// child object Data__c records coming from json
List<Data__c> dList = (List<Data__c>) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonBody, List<Data__c>.class);

Map<String, List<Data__c>> mapCountByData = new Map<String, List<Data__c>>();
for(Data__c d : dList) {
    if(mapCountByData.containsKey(d.count__c)) {
       List<Data__c> lstData = mapCountByData.get(d.count__c);
       lstData.add(d);
       mapCountByData.put(d.count__c, lstData);
    } else {
        mapCountByData.put(d.count__c, new List<Data__c> { d });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maps are the way to go here,

```
List<Data__c> dList = (List<Data__c>) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonBody, List<Data__c>.class);
Map<String, List<Data__c>> mapCountByData = new Map<String, List<Data__c>>();
for(Data__c d : dList) {
    if(mapCountByData.containsKey(d.count__c)) {
       List<Data__c> lstData = mapCountByData.get(d.count__c);
       lstData.add(d);
       mapCountByData.put(d.count__c, lstData);
    } else {
        mapCountByData.put(d.count__c, new List<Data__c> { d });
    }
}
```

Then you can get all the counts using,

```
set<integer> setCounts = mapCountByData.keyset();
```

this will also not have duplicates and you can use the set in the IN clause in SOQL.

Later you can also make use of the `mapCountByData` to get the list of `Data__c` records.

Comment: Thats corrct, thanks. But I get these errors when saving with red squiggly lines on put and lstData:
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void put(String, List<Data__c>) from the type Map<String,Data__c>
Illegal assignment from Data__c to List<Data__c>
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void put(String, List<Data__c>) from the type Map<String,Data__c>

Comment: Just fixed a typo. It’s map with keys as integer

Comment: I had updated the json. count value is string.

Comment: Just updated, check it out

Comment: Yes, that worked! But I can't seem to update a child field based on it parents field value. I have updated the original post above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Set or a List. Sets are preferred.

```
Set<Integer> values = new Set<Integer>();

for(Data__c d : dList){
  values.add(d.count__c);
}
```

Note that Count__c appears to be a number, so we use a number data type. If the actual field is a String, conversion is necessary:

```
Set<String> values = new Set<String>();

for(Data__c d : dList){
  values.add(String.valueOf(d.count__c));
}
```

Comment: My bad. Count was string. Updated json